# Problem with raising/lowering indices in covariant derivative

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I can't show that $\nabla_{a}V^{a}=g^{ac}\nabla_{a}V_{c}$ (I sum latin indices from $0$ to $3$ ) for de Sitter metric:
$$g=\frac{1}{H^2\eta^2}(-1,\:1,\:1,\:1).$$
For that metric the only non-zero Christoffel symbols are:
$$\Gamma^{0}_{00}=\Gamma^{0}_{ii}=\Gamma^{i}_{0i}=\Gamma^{i}_{i0}=-\frac{1}{\eta},$$ where $i\in\{1,2,3\}$
(we don't sum over $i$ here and also below). In order to get $\nabla_{a}V^{a}$ I've calculated:
$$\nabla_{0}V^{0}=\partial_{0}V^{0}+\Gamma^{0}_{d0}V^{d}=\partial_{0}V^{0}+\Gamma^{0}_{00}V^{0}=\partial_{0}V^{0}-\frac{1}{\eta}V^{0}$$
$$\nabla_{i}V^{i}=\partial_{i}V^{i}+\Gamma^{i}_{di}V^{d}=\partial_{i}V^{i}+\Gamma^{i}_{0i}V^{0}=\partial_{i}V^{i}-\frac{1}{\eta}V^{0}$$
So eventually I have $\nabla_{a}V^{a}=\partial_{a}V^{a}-\frac{4}{\eta}V^{0}$. For diagonal metric we have $g^{ac}\nabla_{a}V_{c}=g^{aa}\nabla_{a}V_{a}$, so I've calculated:
$$g^{00}\nabla_{0}V_{0}=g^{00}(\partial_{0}V_{0}-\Gamma^{d}_{00}V_{d})=g^{00}(\partial_{0}V_{0}-\Gamma^{0}_{00}V_{0})=g^{00}\left(\partial_{0}V_{0}+\frac{1}{\eta}V_{0}\right)=g^{00}\partial_{0}V_{0}-H^2\eta^2\frac{1}{\eta}V_{0}=g^{00}\partial_{0}V_{0}-H^2\eta V_{0}$$
$$g^{ii}\nabla_{i}V_{i}=g^{ii}(\partial_{i}V_{i}-\Gamma^{d}_{ii}V_{d})=g^{ii}(\partial_{i}V_{i}-\Gamma^{0}_{ii}V_{0})=g^{ii}\left(\partial_{i}V_{i}+\frac{1}{\eta}V_{0}\right)=g^{ii}\partial_{i}V_{i}+H^2\eta^2\frac{1}{\eta}V_{0}= g^{ii}\partial_{i}V_{i}+H^2\eta V_{0}$$
And in a result:
$$g^{aa}\nabla_{a}V_{a}=g^{aa}\partial_{a}V_{a}-H^2\eta V_{0}+3H^2\eta V_{0}=g^{aa}\partial_{a}V_{a}+2H^2\eta V_{0}=\partial_{a}V^{a}+2H^2\eta V^{d}g_{d0}=\partial_{a}V^{a}+2H^2\eta V^{0}g_{00}=\partial_{a}V^{a}+2H^2\eta\left(-\frac{1}{H^2\eta^2}\right)V^{0}=\partial_{a}V^{a}-\frac{2}{\eta}V^{0},$$
so I got $\nabla_{a}V^{a}\neq g^{ac}\nabla_{a}V_{c}$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Let's first use a third method to know which of the first two for computing the divergence has gone awry: define $g:=\det g_{ab}=-(H\eta)^{-8}$ so$$\nabla_aV^a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_a\left(\sqrt{|g|}V^a\right)=\partial_aV^a+V^a\partial_a\ln\sqrt{|g|}=\partial_aV^a-\tfrac{4}{\eta}V^0.$$This at least tells us none of the non-vanishing Christoffel symbols should have instead been $+\tfrac{1}{\eta}$. The issue you've run into is $\partial_aV^a\ne g^{ac}\partial_aV_c$; or, in more detail,$$\begin{align}g^{ac}\nabla_aV_c&=g^{ac}\partial_aV_c-g^{ac}\Gamma_{ac}^bV_b\\&=\partial_a(g^{ac}V_c)-V_cg^{ac}_{,\,a}-g^{ac}\Gamma_{ac}^bV_b\\&=\partial_aV^a-V_cg^{ac}_{,\,a}-g^{ac}\Gamma_{ac}^bV_b,\end{align}$$so we only need verify$$V_cg^{ac}_{,\,a}+g^{ac}\Gamma_{ac}^bV_b=\tfrac{4}{\eta}V^0=-4H^2\eta V_0.$$Your calculation actually only considered$$g^{ac}\Gamma_{ac}^bV_b=\left(g^{00}\Gamma_{00}^0+\sum_ig^{ii}\Gamma_{ii}^0\right)V_0=-2H^2\eta V_0.$$But$$V_cg^{ac}_{,\,a}=V_0g^{00}_{,\,0}=-2H^2\eta V_0.$$

Comment: Oh I see, thanks a lot!